# Как узнать, сообщение пришло из группы или нет

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, telegram

У меня есть бот, который может быть добавлен в группу.
И ему нужно знать, с группы пришло сообщение, или нет.
Как это сделать?

Comment: Если вы используете polling, то вам нужен метод `getUpdates`. Если же вы используете webhook, то сообщение придет к вам на сервер само.

Comment: @Dareten я понимаю это. Как мне понять пришло сообщение из группы или нет?

Comment: Проверьте в сообщении соответствие `chat.id` сообщений и `id` нужной группы

Comment: @Dareten Ну а если разные группы могут быть. Нету функции которая проверит, группа это или нет?

Comment: проверяйте `message.chat.type`, а так же можете сопоставить id группы с её названием

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я уже сказал в комментарии можно проверять тип чата:

`type String`   *Type of chat, can be either “private”, “group”, “supergroup” or “channel”*

А если бот в нескольких группах участвует, то варьируйте функционал проверяя по `id`.

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chat

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!